# sed/awk - compare files, and return lines that have differences

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I have two files

file1:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

file2:

```
1
2a
3
4
5
6a
```

How can I script something that will return a third file that will output the lines that are different, along with the line number and filename? Ie. as lines 2 and 6 are different, the output is something like this, with a filename of 'file3':

file3

```
file1;line 2;2
file2;line 2;2a
file1;line 6;6
file2;line 6;6a
```

Thankyou as always!

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are looking for [**`diff`**](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?diff) command

type `man diff` on your shell for more detials

Comment: @StephenConstantine Glad that it worked for you! Wondering how you know names `bash`, `sed` and `awk` and didn't come across `diff`. In-fact the very first commands I learnt were `ls`, `cd`, `cat` and `diff`! :)

Answer (score 0):

There are `diff` command as jkshah said. And there are too `vimdiff` tool.

If it's for occasional analysis and not to encapsulated in a script, `vimdiff` is very pleasant to use (using vim therefore allows access to vim commands such as search by regex, but also the syntax highlighting ...). In other words, with vimdiff you have a better visual diff.

```
vimdiff file1 file2
```